# How do I extract an ISO image to an external storage media using java ISO tools

Tags: java, iso

I'm creating a USB writer program. I've heard about java ISO tools, and I want to use it in my program. however, I can't find any tutorials online on how to do that, in fact, I can't even find a single tutorial on how to use it. How do I extract an ISO image to an external storage media  using java ISO tools

Also, I can't paste my code here because it is more than 800 lines of code to read.
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: An example is here: https://github.com/stephenc/java-iso-tools out of the very first Google search I did for "java write iso file" :-)

Comment: thanks, already got the answer from a newer question.